# postgresql - select all old db connections

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to know all the IP address that connected to my postgresql db.

The following:

```
SELECT client_addr 
FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

select all the activity connections,

How can I know all the connections from 30 days ago untill now?

Comment: Not possible. Postgres does not keep a history of that. You would need to roll your own sampling tool that saves the information from that table somewhere else. Or log connections and disconnects and then analyze the logfile

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your response!, Does not postgresql have a default logfile saving the information?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html